# HTML/CSS: Sticky iframe chatbox (using cbox API) input field doesn't scroll with visual chatbox

Tags: html, css, input, textfield, sticky

I'm not sure if this problem is specific to the chatbox API I'm using, cbox, or if this is a general problem, but I haven't found or figured out a solution either way.

I have a chatbox on my webpage, and I've made it have

```
position: sticky;
```

Visually, this does exactly what I want it to do. When you load the page, the chatbox appears in a certain starting location, and after you scroll a certain amount it sticks to the viewport and scrolls down with you.

However, the actual area of the screen you click on to start typing doesn't scroll with it. As the chatbox visually scrolls down, clicking on it stops working, because the input field to click on has somehow become detached, and is still sitting in the position it was in when the webpage originally loaded. You can only use the chatbox when you visually line up the chatbox input field to the "invisible" reactive/clickable input area.

Code is trivial; I've simply imported the chatbox as an iframe, made it sticky... and that's it. This happens regardless of any other formatting.

```
<style>
#chatbox_id
{
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
</style>
```

...

```
<body>
    <iframe id="chatbox_id" src="https://www3.cbox.ws/box/?boxid=somethingsomething" width="100%" height="100%" allowtransparency="yes" allow="autoplay" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
</body>
```

Any help is very much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.